# "RUN go mod download" hang issue when running "make docker-build"

Tags: kubernetes, dockerfile, operators, docker-build

Developers.

I am trying to build my go src files and seeing hanging issue when running "make docker-build". The "hanging" issue happens when Docker runs "RUN go mod download".

In 30 mins, the cmd displays "timeout" err. All of the download-failed go modules already exist in $GOPATH/pkg/mod. However, "RUN go mod download" cmd is still trying to download them and keeps showing the "timeout" msg as below.

```
 Dockerfile
============
# Build the manager binary
FROM golang:1.17 as builder
ENV GOPROXY="https://goproxy.io"

WORKDIR /workspace
# Copy the Go Modules manifests
COPY go.mod go.mod
COPY go.sum go.sum
# cache deps before building and copying source so that we don't need to re-download as much
# and so that source changes don't invalidate our downloaded layer

RUN go mod download

# Copy the go source
COPY main.go main.go
COPY api/ api/
COPY controllers/ controllers/

# Build
RUN CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64 go build -a -o manager main.go

# Use distroless as minimal base image to package the manager binary
# Refer to https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/distroless for more details
FROM gcr.io/distroless/static:nonroot
WORKDIR /
COPY --from=builder /workspace/manager .
#USER 65532:65532

ENTRYPOINT ["/manager"]
```

```
  Output of "make docker-build"
=================================
bash-4.4$ make docker-build
go: creating new go.mod: module tmp
Downloading sigs.k8s.io/controller-tools/cmd/controller-gen@v0.7.0
go: added github.com/fatih/color v1.12.0
go: added github.com/go-logr/logr v0.4.0
go: added github.com/gobuffalo/flect v0.2.3
go: added github.com/gogo/protobuf v1.3.2
go: added github.com/google/go-cmp v0.5.6
go: added github.com/google/gofuzz v1.1.0
go: added github.com/inconshreveable/mousetrap v1.0.0
go: added github.com/json-iterator/go v1.1.11
go: added github.com/mattn/go-colorable v0.1.8
go: added github.com/mattn/go-isatty v0.0.12
go: added github.com/modern-go/concurrent v0.0.0-20180306012644-bacd9c7ef1dd
go: added github.com/modern-go/reflect2 v1.0.1
go: added github.com/spf13/cobra v1.2.1
go: added github.com/spf13/pflag v1.0.5
go: added golang.org/x/mod v0.4.2
go: added golang.org/x/net v0.0.0-20210520170846-37e1c6afe023
go: added golang.org/x/sys v0.0.0-20210616094352-59db8d763f22
go: added golang.org/x/text v0.3.6
go: added golang.org/x/tools v0.1.5
go: added golang.org/x/xerrors v0.0.0-20200804184101-5ec99f83aff1
go: added gopkg.in/inf.v0 v0.9.1
go: added gopkg.in/yaml.v2 v2.4.0
go: added gopkg.in/yaml.v3 v3.0.0-20210107192922-496545a6307b
go: added k8s.io/api v0.22.2
go: added k8s.io/apiextensions-apiserver v0.22.2
go: added k8s.io/apimachinery v0.22.2
go: added k8s.io/klog/v2 v2.9.0
go: added k8s.io/utils v0.0.0-20210819203725-bdf08cb9a70a
go: added sigs.k8s.io/controller-tools v0.7.0
go: added sigs.k8s.io/structured-merge-diff/v4 v4.1.2
go: added sigs.k8s.io/yaml v1.2.0
controller-gen rbac:roleName=manager-role crd webhook paths="./..." output:crd:artifacts:config=config/crd/bases
controller-gen object:headerFile="hack/boilerplate.go.txt" paths="./..."
go fmt ./...
go vet ./...
KUBEBUILDER_ASSETS="/auto/BTS/lalabs/.local/share/kubebuilder-envtest/k8s/1.22.1-linux-amd64" go test ./... -coverprofile cover.out
?       operator    [no test files]
?       operator/api/v1alpha1   [no test files]
ok      operator/controllers    7.682s  coverage: 0.0% of statements
docker build -t example.com/operator:v0.0.1 .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  191.5kB
Step 1/14 : FROM golang:1.17 as builder
 ---> b6bd03a3a78e
Step 2/14 : ENV GOPROXY="https://goproxy.io"
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 7421d542fbca
Step 3/14 : WORKDIR /workspace
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 44a452e145ab
Step 4/14 : COPY go.mod go.mod
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 7f04e67abe54
Step 5/14 : COPY go.sum go.sum
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 6af683163d53
Step 6/14 : RUN go mod download  *<<< Hanging HERE and shows timeout in 30min.*
 ---> Running in c5c809db5712
go mod download: cloud.google.com/go@v0.81.0: Get "https://goproxy.io/cloud.google.com/go/@v/v0.81.0.info": dial tcp 119.28.201.50:443: i/o timeout
go mod download: github.com/Azure/go-autorest@v14.2.0+incompatible: Get "https://goproxy.io/github.com/%21azure/go-autorest/@v/v14.2.0+incompatible.info": dial tcp 119.28.201.50:443: i/o timeout
go mod download: github.com/Azure/go-autorest/autorest@v0.11.18: Get "https://goproxy.io/github.com/%21azure/go-autorest/autorest/@v/v0.11.18.info": dial tcp 119.28.201.50:443: i/o timeout
go mod download: github.com/Azure/go-autorest/autorest/adal@v0.9.13: Get "https://goproxy.io/github.com/%21azure/go-autorest/autorest/adal/@v/v0.9.13.info": dial tcp 119.28.201.50:443: i/o timeout
go mod download: github.com/Azure/go-autorest/autorest/date@v0.3.0: Get "https://goproxy.io/github.com/%21azure/go-autorest/autorest/date/@v/v0.3.0.info": dial tcp 119.28.201.50:443: i/o timeout
go mod download: github.com/Azure/go-autorest/logger@v0.2.1: Get "https://goproxy.io/github.com/%21azure/go-autorest/logger/@v/v0.2.1.info": dial tcp 119.28.201.50:443: i/o timeout
go mod download: github.com/Azure/go-autorest/tracing@v0.6.0: Get "https://goproxy.io/github.com/%21azure/go-autorest/tracing/@v/v0.6.0.info": dial tcp 119.28.201.50:443: i/o timeout
go mod download: github.com/beorn7/perks@v1.0.1: Get "https://goproxy.io/github.com/beorn7/perks/@v/v1.0.1.info": dial tcp 119.28.201.50:443: i/o timeout
go mod download: github.com/cespare/xxhash/v2@v2.1.1: Get "https://goproxy.io/github.com/cespare/xxhash/v2/@v/v2.1.1.info": dial tcp 119.28.201.50:443: i/o timeout
go mod download: github.com/davecgh/go-spew@v1.1.1: Get "https://goproxy.io/github.com/davecgh/go-spew/@v/v1.1.1.info": dial tcp 119.28.201.50:443: i/o timeout
go mod download: github.com/evanphx/json-patch@v4.12.0+incompatible: Get "https://goproxy.io/github.com/evanphx/json-patch/@v/v4.12.0+incompatible.info": dial tcp 119.28.201.50:443: i/o timeout
go mod download: github.com/form3tech-oss/jwt-go@v3.2.3+incompatible: Get "https://goproxy.io/github.com/form3tech-oss/jwt-go/@v/v3.2.3+incompatible.info": dial tcp 119.28.201.50:443: i/o timeout
go mod download: github.com/fsnotify/fsnotify@v1.5.1: Get "https://goproxy.io/github.com/fsnotify/fsnotify/@v/v1.5.1.info": dial tcp 119.28.201.50:443: i/o timeout
go mod download: github.com/go-logr/logr@v1.2.0: Get "https://goproxy.io/github.com/go-logr/logr/@v/v1.2.0.info": dial tcp 119.28.201.50:443: i/o timeout
go mod download: github.com/go-logr/zapr@v1.2.0: Get "https://goproxy.io/github.com/go-logr/zapr/@v/v1.2.0.info": dial tcp 119.28.201.50:443: i/o timeout
go mod download: github.com/gogo/protobuf@v1.3.2: Get "https://goproxy.io/github.com/gogo/protobuf/@v/v1.3.2.info": dial tcp 119.28.201.50:443: i/o timeout
go mod download: github.com/golang/groupcache@v0.0.0-20210331224755-41bb18bfe9da: Get "https://goproxy.io/github.com/golang/groupcache/@v/v0.0.0-20210331224755-41bb18bfe9da.info": dial tcp 119.28.201.50:443: i/o timeout
go mod download: github.com/golang/protobuf@v1.5.2: Get "https://goproxy.io/github.com/golang/protobuf/@v/v1.5.2.info": dial tcp 119.28.201.50:443: i/o timeout
go mod download: github.com/google/go-cmp@v0.5.5: Get "https://goproxy.io/github.com/google/go-cmp/@v/v0.5.5.info": dial tcp 119.28.201.50:443: i/o timeout
go mod download: github.com/google/gofuzz@v1.1.0: Get "https://goproxy.io/github.com/google/gofuzz/@v/v1.1.0.info": dial tcp 119.28.201.50:443: i/o timeout
go mod download: github.com/google/uuid@v1.1.2: Get "https://goproxy.io/github.com/google/uuid/@v/v1.1.2.info": dial tcp 119.28.201.50:443: i/o timeout
go mod download: github.com/googleapis/gnostic@v0.5.5: Get "https://goproxy.io/github.com/googleapis/gnostic/@v/v0.5.5.info": dial tcp 119.28.201.50:443: i/o timeout
go mod download: github.com/imdario/mergo@v0.3.12: Get "https://goproxy.io/github.com/imdario/mergo/@v/v0.3.12.info": dial tcp 119.28.201.50:443: i/o timeout
go mod download: github.com/json-iterator/go@v1.1.12: Get "https://goproxy.io/github.com/json-iterator/go/@v/v1.1.12.info": dial tcp 119.28.201.50:443: i/o timeout
go mod download: github.com/matttproud/golang_protobuf_extensions@v1.0.2-0.20181231171920-c182affec369: Get "https://goproxy.io/github.com/matttproud/golang_protobuf_extensions/@v/v1.0.2-0.20181231171920-c182affec369.info": dial tcp 119.28.201.50:443: i/o timeout
go mod download: github.com/modern-go/concurrent@v0.0.0-20180306012644-bacd9c7ef1dd: Get "https://goproxy.io/github.com/modern-go/concurrent/@v/v0.0.0-20180306012644-bacd9c7ef1dd.info": dial tcp 119.28.201.50:443: i/o timeout
go mod download: github.com/modern-go/reflect2@v1.0.2: Get "https://goproxy.io/github.com/modern-go/reflect2/@v/v1.0.2.info": dial tcp 119.28.201.50:443: i/o timeout
go mod download: github.com/nxadm/tail@v1.4.8: Get "https://goproxy.io/github.com/nxadm/tail/@v/v1.4.8.info": dial tcp 119.28.201.50:443: i/o timeout
go mod download: github.com/onsi/ginkgo@v1.16.5: Get "https://goproxy.io/github.com/onsi/ginkgo/@v/v1.16.5.info": dial tcp 119.28.201.50:443: i/o timeout
go mod download: github.com/onsi/gomega@v1.17.0: Get "https://goproxy.io/github.com/onsi/gomega/@v/v1.17.0.info": dial tcp 119.28.201.50:443: i/o timeout
go mod download: github.com/pkg/errors@v0.9.1: Get "https://goproxy.io/github.com/pkg/errors/@v/v0.9.1.info": dial tcp 119.28.201.50:443: i/o timeout
go mod download: github.com/prometheus/client_golang@v1.11.0: Get "https://goproxy.io/github.com/prometheus/client_golang/@v/v1.11.0.info": dial tcp 119.28.201.50:443: i/o timeout
go mod download: github.com/prometheus/client_model@v0.2.0: Get "https://goproxy.io/github.com/prometheus/client_model/@v/v0.2.0.info": dial tcp 119.28.201.50:443: i/o timeout
go mod download: github.com/prometheus/common@v0.28.0: Get "https://goproxy.io/github.com/prometheus/common/@v/v0.28.0.info": dial tcp 119.28.201.50:443: i/o timeout
go mod download: github.com/prometheus/procfs@v0.6.0: Get "https://goproxy.io/github.com/prometheus/procfs/@v/v0.6.0.info": dial tcp 119.28.201.50:443: i/o timeout
go mod download: github.com/spf13/pflag@v1.0.5: Get "https://goproxy.io/github.com/spf13/pflag/@v/v1.0.5.info": dial tcp 119.28.201.50:443: i/o timeout
go mod download: go.uber.org/atomic@v1.7.0: Get "https://goproxy.io/go.uber.org/atomic/@v/v1.7.0.info": dial tcp 119.28.201.50:443: i/o timeout
go mod download: go.uber.org/multierr@v1.6.0: Get "https://goproxy.io/go.uber.org/multierr/@v/v1.6.0.info": dial tcp 119.28.201.50:443: i/o timeout
go mod download: go.uber.org/zap@v1.19.1: Get "https://goproxy.io/go.uber.org/zap/@v/v1.19.1.info": dial tcp 119.28.201.50:443: i/o timeout
go mod download: golang.org/x/crypto@v0.0.0-20210817164053-32db794688a5: Get "https://goproxy.io/golang.org/x/crypto/@v/v0.0.0-20210817164053-32db794688a5.info": dial tcp 119.28.201.50:443: i/o timeout
go mod download: golang.org/x/net@v0.0.0-20210825183410-e898025ed96a: Get "https://goproxy.io/golang.org/x/net/@v/v0.0.0-20210825183410-e898025ed96a.info": dial tcp 119.28.201.50:443: i/o timeout
go mod download: golang.org/x/oauth2@v0.0.0-20210819190943-2bc19b11175f: Get "https://goproxy.io/golang.org/x/oauth2/@v/v0.0.0-20210819190943-2bc19b11175f.info": dial tcp 119.28.201.50:443: i/o timeout
go mod download: golang.org/x/sys@v0.0.0-20211029165221-6e7872819dc8: Get "https://goproxy.io/golang.org/x/sys/@v/v0.0.0-20211029165221-6e7872819dc8.info": dial tcp 119.28.201.50:443: i/o timeout
go mod download: golang.org/x/term@v0.0.0-20210615171337-6886f2dfbf5b: Get "https://goproxy.io/golang.org/x/term/@v/v0.0.0-20210615171337-6886f2dfbf5b.info": dial tcp 119.28.201.50:443: i/o timeout
go mod download: golang.org/x/text@v0.3.7: Get "https://goproxy.io/golang.org/x/text/@v/v0.3.7.info": dial tcp 119.28.201.50:443: i/o timeout
go mod download: golang.org/x/time@v0.0.0-20210723032227-1f47c861a9ac: Get "https://goproxy.io/golang.org/x/time/@v/v0.0.0-20210723032227-1f47c861a9ac.info": dial tcp 119.28.201.50:443: i/o timeout
go mod download: gomodules.xyz/jsonpatch/v2@v2.2.0: Get "https://goproxy.io/gomodules.xyz/jsonpatch/v2/@v/v2.2.0.info": dial tcp 119.28.201.50:443: i/o timeout
go mod download: google.golang.org/appengine@v1.6.7: Get "https://goproxy.io/google.golang.org/appengine/@v/v1.6.7.info": dial tcp 119.28.201.50:443: i/o timeout
go mod download: google.golang.org/protobuf@v1.27.1: Get "https://goproxy.io/google.golang.org/protobuf/@v/v1.27.1.info": dial tcp 119.28.201.50:443: i/o timeout
go mod download: gopkg.in/inf.v0@v0.9.1: Get "https://goproxy.io/gopkg.in/inf.v0/@v/v0.9.1.info": dial tcp 119.28.201.50:443: i/o timeout
go mod download: gopkg.in/tomb.v1@v1.0.0-20141024135613-dd632973f1e7: Get "https://goproxy.io/gopkg.in/tomb.v1/@v/v1.0.0-20141024135613-dd632973f1e7.info": dial tcp 119.28.201.50:443: i/o timeout
go mod download: gopkg.in/yaml.v2@v2.4.0: Get "https://goproxy.io/gopkg.in/yaml.v2/@v/v2.4.0.info": dial tcp 119.28.201.50:443: i/o timeout
go mod download: gopkg.in/yaml.v3@v3.0.0-20210107192922-496545a6307b: Get "https://goproxy.io/gopkg.in/yaml.v3/@v/v3.0.0-20210107192922-496545a6307b.info": dial tcp 119.28.201.50:443: i/o timeout
go mod download: k8s.io/api@v0.23.0: Get "https://goproxy.io/k8s.io/api/@v/v0.23.0.info": dial tcp 119.28.201.50:443: i/o timeout
go mod download: k8s.io/apiextensions-apiserver@v0.23.0: Get "https://goproxy.io/k8s.io/apiextensions-apiserver/@v/v0.23.0.info": dial tcp 119.28.201.50:443: i/o timeout
go mod download: k8s.io/apimachinery@v0.23.0: Get "https://goproxy.io/k8s.io/apimachinery/@v/v0.23.0.info": dial tcp 119.28.201.50:443: i/o timeout
go mod download: k8s.io/client-go@v0.23.0: Get "https://goproxy.io/k8s.io/client-go/@v/v0.23.0.info": dial tcp 119.28.201.50:443: i/o timeout
go mod download: k8s.io/component-base@v0.23.0: Get "https://goproxy.io/k8s.io/component-base/@v/v0.23.0.info": dial tcp 119.28.201.50:443: i/o timeout
go mod download: k8s.io/klog/v2@v2.30.0: Get "https://goproxy.io/k8s.io/klog/v2/@v/v2.30.0.info": dial tcp 119.28.201.50:443: i/o timeout
go mod download: k8s.io/kube-openapi@v0.0.0-20211115234752-e816edb12b65: Get "https://goproxy.io/k8s.io/kube-openapi/@v/v0.0.0-20211115234752-e816edb12b65.info": dial tcp 119.28.201.50:443: i/o timeout
go mod download: k8s.io/utils@v0.0.0-20210930125809-cb0fa318a74b: Get "https://goproxy.io/k8s.io/utils/@v/v0.0.0-20210930125809-cb0fa318a74b.info": dial tcp 119.28.201.50:443: i/o timeout
go mod download: sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime@v0.11.0: Get "https://goproxy.io/sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime/@v/v0.11.0.info": dial tcp 119.28.201.50:443: i/o timeout
go mod download: sigs.k8s.io/json@v0.0.0-20211020170558-c049b76a60c6: Get "https://goproxy.io/sigs.k8s.io/json/@v/v0.0.0-20211020170558-c049b76a60c6.info": dial tcp 119.28.201.50:443: i/o timeout
go mod download: sigs.k8s.io/structured-merge-diff/v4@v4.2.0: Get "https://goproxy.io/sigs.k8s.io/structured-merge-diff/v4/@v/v4.2.0.info": dial tcp 119.28.201.50:443: i/o timeout
go mod download: sigs.k8s.io/yaml@v1.3.0: Get "https://goproxy.io/sigs.k8s.io/yaml/@v/v1.3.0.info": dial tcp 119.28.201.50:443: i/o timeout
The command '/bin/sh -c go mod download' returned a non-zero code: 1
make: *** [Makefile:108: docker-build] Error 1
```

```
 Dev Env
==========
bash-4.4$ go version
go version go1.18 linux/amd64

bash-4.4$ docker version
Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Version:           20.10.12
 API version:       1.41
 Go version:        go1.16.12
 Git commit:        e91ed57
 Built:             Mon Dec 13 11:45:22 2021
 OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
 Context:           default
 Experimental:      true

Server: Docker Engine - Community
 Engine:
  Version:          20.10.12
  API version:      1.41 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.16.12
  Git commit:       459d0df
  Built:            Mon Dec 13 11:43:44 2021
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
 containerd:
  Version:          1.4.12
  GitCommit:        7b11cfaabd73bb80907dd23182b9347b4245eb5d
 runc:
  Version:          1.0.2
  GitCommit:        v1.0.2-0-g52b36a2
 docker-init:
  Version:          0.19.0
  GitCommit:        de40ad0
```

Comment: Hi lalabs welcome to SO. It's almost certainly because your computer has access to a corporate proxy that the docker host does not. Please make use of [the extensive search system](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bdocker%5D+i%2Fo+timeout) to get the maximum benefit out of your stay in the stack exchange network. Good luck

Comment: @mdaniel, Thanks! THe issue has been resolved.

Comment: Please don't be [that person](https://xkcd.com/979/); you can [add and accept your own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) in order to let others know how you solved the problem. If it was in fact a duplicate of the other docker and proxy problems, you can delete this

Comment: This is a proxy issue. After adding the company-proprietary proxy addr to Dockerfile, the issue was resolved. ENV HTTP_PROXY=".." ENV HTTPS_PROXY="..."

Comment: Thanks for reading what I wrote; I'm sure you're going to have a great time here in the stack exchange network. Also, that's an incorrect fix because it will cause those who _execute_ that Docker container to also use the proxy, which is almost guaranteed to cause its own stack overflow duplicate question